# ASP.NET, C#, MySQL : fetch data form data base using stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying fetch data from MySQL database using a stored procedure in C#. To be more precise am following tri layer architecture; I am not sure where I am going wrong in the following below code I have tried in all the possibilities small help would be appreciated a lot.

DataServices layer:

```
    public DataSet FetchLoginDetails(string SchoolID)
    {
        object[] objparam = new object[1];
        objparam[0] = new MySqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@SchoolID",
            DbType = System.Data.DbType.String,
            Value =SchoolID
        };

        DataSet dsdataRes = ExecuteQuery("StoredProcedure", objparam);
        return dsdataRes;
    }
```

BusinessServices

```
    private ITimeTableRepository ObjTimeTable
    {
        get { return UnityManager.Resolve<ITimeTableRepository>(); }
    }

    public DataSet FetchLoginDetails(string SchoolID)
    {
        return ObjTimeTable.FetchLoginDetails(SchoolID);
    }
```

BusinessServices.Interfaces

```
public interface ITimeTableBO
{
    DataSet FetchLoginDetails(string SchoolID);
}
```

UI .cs

```
public void LoadLoginDetails(DataSet ds)
{
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ddlSubject.Items.Clear();

            ListItem item1 = new ListItem();
            item1.Text = "Choose a Subject";
            item1.Value = "-1";

            ddlSubject.Items.Add(item1);

            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                ListItem item = new ListItem();
                item.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UserName"].ToString();
                item.Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UserName"].ToString();

                ddlSubject.Items.Add(item);
             }
         }
    }
}
```

ASPX markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubject" runat="server" Width="150px" 
     Height="27px" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" >
     <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="Choose a Subject"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `StoredProcedure`(
SchoolID 

VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN

select UserName from scoolage_login where SchoolID = 

SchoolID ;


END
```

Comment: You have not specified which Stored Procedure to call in FetchLoginDetails.

Comment: @Drew am sorry that was my error while posting in my code i have mentioned the store procedure name but still it is not showing up

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the other details of your code, I am assuming you are unable to connect and retrieve data from your MySQL database. Take a look at the `MySqlCommand` class. There are code examples as well:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html

Try something like this:

```
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("StoredProcedure", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchoolID", SchoolID);

            using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                // Do something with results
            }
        }
    }
```

See this SO question as well:

[calling mysql storedprocedure from c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545114/calling-mysql-storedprocedure-from-c)

Comment: Drew Thank you for the support if u have no issue i can share my screen via Team viewer u can have a look that would be more precise

Comment: Hi Shaik, I have added an example that should help you get started. Please accept as the answer if your issue is resolved.